# "I throw the ball in the room"

Tags: prepositions

I throw the ball in the room. I throw the dish in the bar. Two preposition phrase modify a clause.
Can I express it with 'I throw the ball and I throw the dish in the bar'?

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! I don't know why exactly your question has been downvoted but can you be a little clearer on what you are asking? There is no "in" in "I throw the ball".

Comment: I mean a preposition phrase 'in the room'

Comment: I admit the question was unclear, but can we leave a comment rather than downvoting new members right away? We should encourage new members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question is

> I throw the ball in the room.
> I learn that a preposition qualifies a verb, adjective and adverb. That means preposition 'in' doesn't qualify 'I throw the ball'?

My answer to that question follows:
(The original poster has edited the question to be something else, instead of posting a new question, and this answer may not apply to that.)

A preposition is the head of a preposition phrase, consisting of the preposition and its complement. The phrase here is "in the room".
The preposition by itself doesn't qualify anything.
That preposition phrase acts as an adverb, and it can be viewed as modifying the verb "throw" or the entire clause "I throw the ball". It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: but modifying the entire clause needs a comma

Comment: @ksssss I don't think so.

Comment: if there are two clauses, can a preposition phrase qualify only one clause or two clauses?

Comment: @ksssss I don't know what you are referring to. Is this a new question?

Comment: yes this is a new question

Comment: @ksssss  I think it would be better to formulate it as a new question, along with an example or two of exactly what you mean, rather than trying to deal with it in a comment train.

Comment: no I revise it.